# Escaping ; () in echo

Tags: bash, echo

how could i escaping `;` or `()` or `""` in echo ?
I want to echo this command

```
"LOAD DATA INPATH '$i' INTO TABLE transient.url_log_201803 partition (ds='$TGLS', periode='$WKTS');"
```

but it says, `syntax error near unexpected token`}'`
even i have changed that command with escaping single quote like this

```
'LOAD DATA INPATH '"'"$i"'"' INTO TABLE transient.url_log_201803 partition (ds='"'"$TGLS"'"', periode='"'"$WKTS"'"');'
```

I don't know how to echo that command into terminal or file. And also i tried to use `\` for escaping and nothing

Comment: Your command doesn't have a `}` in it...are you showing us everything?  Are you trying to prevent the variables from expanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to prevent the variables from expanding you need to escape the `$` with `\`.  It may seem unnecessary due to the variables being single quoted however the double quotes around the single quotes cause the single quotes to be interpreted literally:

```
$ echo "LOAD DATA INPATH '$i' INTO TABLE transient.url_log_201803 partition (ds='$TGLS', periode='$WKTS');"
LOAD DATA INPATH '' INTO TABLE transient.url_log_201803 partition (ds='', periode='');
```

Escape variables:

```
$ echo "LOAD DATA INPATH '\$i' INTO TABLE transient.url_log_201803 partition (ds='\$TGLS', periode='\$WKTS');"
LOAD DATA INPATH '$i' INTO TABLE transient.url_log_201803 partition (ds='$TGLS', periode='$WKTS');
```

If your intent was to keep the double quotes around the whole thing:

```
$ echo "\"LOAD DATA INPATH '\$i' INTO TABLE transient.url_log_201803 partition (ds='\$TGLS', periode='\$WKTS');\""
"LOAD DATA INPATH '$i' INTO TABLE transient.url_log_201803 partition (ds='$TGLS', periode='$WKTS');"
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to use `echo` with complicated data.

The following uses a here-document:

```
cat <<END_SQL
LOAD DATA INPATH '$i' INTO TABLE transient.url_log_201803 PARTITION (ds='$TGLS', periode='$WKTS');
END_SQL
```

If you need to pipe this to a command such as `mysql` (this is a Hive SQL command, but I don't know what the Hive client is usually called, so I use `mysql` in the examples):

```
cat <<END_SQL | mysql
LOAD DATA INPATH '$i' INTO TABLE transient.url_log_201803 PARTITION (ds='$TGLS', periode='$WKTS');
END_SQL
```

If you need to pass it without expanding the variables:

```
cat <<'END_SQL' | mysql
LOAD DATA INPATH '$i' INTO TABLE transient.url_log_201803 PARTITION (ds='$TGLS', periode='$WKTS');
END_SQL
```

Using a here-document also allows you write more readable code (shorter lines):

```
cat <<'END_SQL' | mysql
LOAD DATA INPATH '$i'
INTO TABLE transient.url_log_201803
     PARTITION (ds='$TGLS', periode='$WKTS');
END_SQL
```

Note that the document contents and (more importantly) the end tag (`END_SQL` above) should not be indented:

```
for ...some loop range...; do
    cat <<END_SQL | mysql
LOAD DATA INPATH '$i'
INTO TABLE transient.url_log_201803
     PARTITION (ds='$TGLS', periode='$WKTS');
END_SQL
done
```

If the end tag is indented, the shell won't find it and you will get an error message about the here-document being terminated by end of file.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to escape parens or semicolons with `echo`:

```
$ echo "Semicolons look like ';'.  Parens look like '(' and ')'."
Semicolons look like ';'.  Parens look like '(' and ')'.
```